# what does the following shell script do

Tags: shell, makefile

i came across following shell script as part of makefile in u-boot.
what it does and how is it evaluated

```
cc-option = $(shell if $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(1) -S -o /dev/null -xc /dev/null \
        > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "$(1)"; else echo "$(2)"; fi ;)
```

it is called as

```
PLATFORM_RELFLAGS +=$(call cc-option,-mshort-load-bytes,\
            $(call cc-option,-malignment-traps,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code runs the `if` command. `if` takes one argument: A command to execute (`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(1) -S -o /dev/null -xc /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1`).

If the command succeeds, the `then` part is executed (`echo "$(1)"`). If the command fails, the `else` part is executed (`echo "$(2)"`).

In your case, the compiler is started with some options which it might not support (`$1` is `-mshort-load-bytes`).

Since `$2` is empty, the result will either be the option (if the compiler supports it) or the empty string.

Comment: +1, but "if" is not a command. It is a keyword in the shell grammar.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Well, in most shells "if" is a shell builtin command. The BASH manual lists `if` under "Compound Commands"

Comment: The semantics of "if" is indeed described under that section, as a keyword for forming compound commands.  It is not a command.